# No muestra datos del menú

Tags: c++

[image: Esto es lo que sucede cuando quiero buscar un producto que ya antes he capturado, no me muestra nada, pero tampoco me muestra mensaje de que no exista tal articulo]En mi código ya hice las funciones para cada caso, pero a la hora de llamarlas y correr el programa no me muestra que haya guardado algún dato que ya he capturado. Me corre sin marcar ningún error, pero al final no me muestra nada.

```
class Articulo{

public:
    string referencia;
    string nombre;
    int existente;
    int compra;
    int venta;

    void capturar();
    void mostrar();
    void buscar();

};
```

cuando corrí  estas sin un menú funcionaron muy bien sin un menú

```
void Articulo::capturar(){
    cout<<"\t***INGRESAR ARTICULO NUEVO***\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"NOMBRE DEL ARTICULO:  ";cin>>nombre;
    cout<<"CANTIDAD EXISTENTE: ";cin>>existente;
    cout<<"PRECIO DE COMPRA: ";cin>>compra;
    cout<<"PRECIO DE VENTA: ";cin>>venta;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\tREGISTRO COMPLETADO CORRECTAMENTE\n"<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
};

void Articulo::mostrar(){
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"***DATOS CAPTURADOS***"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"NOMBRE DEL ARTICULO:  "<<nombre;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"CANTIDAD EXISTENTE: "<<existente;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"PRECIO DE COMPRA: "<<compra;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"PRECIO DE VENTA: "<<venta;
    cout<<endl;
};
```

`void Articulo::buscar` realmente no se si sea la mejor opción para hacer la busqueda, si me podrían dar una mejor sería muy bueno!

```
     void Articulo::buscar(){
    string nombre2;
    cout<<"Escriba el nombre del articulo que desea buscar: ";
    cin>>nombre2;
    if(nombre2==nombre)
    {
        cout<<"ARTICULO ENCONTRADO"<<endl<<endl;
        Articulo datos2;
        datos2.mostrar();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"EL ARTICULO NO EXISTE"<<endl;
    }
}

   int main(){
```

Esto que dice `Articulo datos` lo utilice para que me pudiera funcionar el caso numero 1, y funciono.

```
     Articulo datos;
     Articulo datos1;
     Articulo datos2;
     int opcion;
     opcion=0;
     do{
         cout<<"\n  \t***MEN\351 PRINCIPAL***\n"<<endl<<endl;
         cout<<" 1.CAPTURAR \n";
         cout<<" 2.MOSTRAR \n";
         cout<<" 3.BUSCAR \n";
         cout<<" 4.Salir \n";
         cout<<"Eliga una opci\242n: ";
         cin>>opcion;
         switch(opcion){
```

En la opción número uno, solamente me deja capturar un articulo, si trato de poner más se borrar, no lo entiendo porque estoy guardando cada dato en un cin, a menos que se tenga que utilizar alguna otra para que me pueda estar guardando más de un dato.

```
             case 1:
                  system("CLS");
                  datos.capturar();
                  system("PAUSE");
                  system("CLS");
                  break;
```

Esta opción, deberia mostrarme el articulo que previamente registre, pero lo que sucede es que no me lo muestra, solo imprime lo de los cout y no lo demás

```
             case 2:
                  system("CLS");
                  datos1.mostrar();
                  system("PAUSE");
                  system("CLS");
                  break;
```

Cuando pruebo esta opción si me aparece que escriba el nombre del articulo que deseo buscar, pero cuando lo escribo es un articulo que previamente capture, me aparece que no existe ese articulo, pero lo que no comprendo es que utilice el mismo método que con la opción número 1

```
             case 3:
                  system("CLS");
                  datos2.buscar();
                  system("PAUSE");
                  system("CLS");
                  break;
```

Los caso 4 & default funcionan sin ningún problema

```
             case 4:
                  cout<<"\tFIN DEL PROGRAMA\n";
                  opcion = 4;
                  break;
             default:
                  cout<<"\tE R R O R\n";
                  system("PAUSE");
                  system("CLS");
                  break;
        }
     }while(opcion != 4);


     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Porqué usas un objeto diferente para cada caso?

Answer (score 3):

Lo que sucede es que tu estas guardando los datos en el objeto `Articulos datos` y quieres mostrarlos en `Articulos datos2`, cada que instancias un objeto, los métodos y variables son propias del objeto, no de la clase, te enexo un ejemplo sencillo para ver si queda mas claro

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class obj{
    public:
        int variable;

        obj(int a){
            variable = a;
        }
};

int main()
{
    obj primer_objeto(5);
    obj segundo_objeto(100);

    cout<<primer_objeto.variable<<endl;
    cout<<segundo_objeto.variable<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

**Salida**

```
5
100
```

Como puedes ver en el código he creado dos objetos de la clase `obj`, y le asigne a `variable` valores diferentes para cada objeto, que puedes ver en la salida, eso mismo sucede con tu código, estas guardando la información en `datos`, pero quieres mostrarla con el objeto `datos1`, y en este objeto aun no hay datos guardados por lo cual no te mostrara nada, para que tu código funcione deberías usar el mismo objeto `datos` para todo el código.

no tengo la pc para replicar el código, en caso de no funcionar lo que digo avísame para editar mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funciono mucho el ejemplo que me mandaste, y obviamente modifique el `datos1` por `datos`
Ahora solo tengo un problemita, cuando doy en la opción de buscar (3), no me muestra los datos he guardado
Pondré una foto de lo que me muestra en la publicación